# Symfony - Placing Entities outside of any Bundle

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm trying to place Entities outside of my Symfony project because i want the Doctrine entities to be shared with something else. I read the doc and came up with this in config.yml

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping:   false
    mappings:
        backend:
            type:   annotation
            dir:    %kernel.root_dir%/../../common/Backend/Entity
            prefix: Backend\Entity
            alias: Backend
            is_bundle:  false
```

However, when i start the app/try to load a page that depends on data, i get this error:

```
[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]  
  Class 'Backend\Entity\PortalUser' does not exist
```

I am guessing i need to tell Symfony to look into a directory, but i thought that was accomplished by the "dir" config. So i am missing something here.

Autoload config in composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
           "": ["src/","../common/"]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/AppKernel.php"
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the autoload configuration like on your composer.json? This is what's failing.

Comment: i had to run composer update after updating the composer.json (facepalm).. that was all. thanks for your help